# Is there any Thing to make this cube climb in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make the cube climb on the green blocks.I used Friction and Increased Force but Nothing happended.I wanted to make a game like Samsung Edge.

[image: This is my setup currently]

I am using RigidBody to control
[image]

Comment: Judging by the picture you posted, there is no way that cube is going to climb on the green cube as it's center of gravity is well below the edge of the green cube. You will have to use some kind of teleportation/snapping, as the only way to make that work is to go around conventional physic simulation.

Comment: Please add your code as text, not image. Code from an image cannot be copied and tested, plus it is very hard to read

Comment: Sorry thank u for the suggestion i am new here!

Answer (score -1):

If you want the cube to move by rotation I believe the function to use would be `AddTorque()` - [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html), it's a force you apply at a specific place of rigidbody. Then you have to experiment with friction and location of the torque you apply to get the effect you want.